# how to get realesacpe value in database field + mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to select data in database use select query like this.

```
$qry ="select contact from sip_registrations where sip_user='1234567890'";
$sip_contact = mysql_query($qry);   
echo "<pre>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sip_contact)){
   print_r($row); 
}
```

Print result is below.

```
Array
(
   [contact] => "1234567890" 
)
```

But in database contact field value like this

```
mysql> select sip_user,contact from sip_registrations where sip_user='1234567890'";;
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sip_user    | contact                                                                                                                                         |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1234567890 | "1234567890" <sip:1234567890@192.XX.XXX.XX:XXX;line=13fc8fc06d07efc;fs_path=sip%3A196.31.25.91%3Blr%3Breceived%3Dsip%3AXXX.XX.XXX.16%3A5066> |

+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Actually i need to return array value like this

```
Array
(
   [contact] => "1234567890" <sip:1234567890@192.XX.XXX.XX:XXXX;line=13fc8fc06d07efc;fs_path=sip%3A196.31.25.91%3Blr%3Breceived%3Dsip%3AXXX.XX.XXX.16%3A5066> 
)
```

Any ideas what I need to do to make this work ? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. Please migrate to either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: What field type is `contact`?  This doesn't make sense to me, MySQL wouldn't return a *partial* field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you string contain `<>` tag . To display it Use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) which  Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sip_contact)){
     echo htmlentities($row['contact']); 
}
```

> NOTE:- mysql is  deprecated instead use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1):

all code are running well. just html content are rendering but not displaying due to html tag.

htmlspecialchars(): PHP function used to convert the predefined characters "<" (less than) and ">" (greater than) to HTML entities.

use this

```
print_r(htmlspecialchars($row['contact']));
```

instead of 
print_r($row);